# how to redirect using react router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

The maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom"; 
  import Login from "./component/auth/Login";
  import HomeScreen from "./component/home-screen/HomeScreen";
       class App extends Component {
           constructor(props) {
            super(props);

              this.state = {
                   user: {}
                 };
                 }

              componentDidMount() {
                    this.authListener();
               }

     authListener() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ user });
  } else {
    this.setState({ user: null });
  }
});
}

render() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        {this.state.user ? (
          <Redirect to="/homescreen" />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )}
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/homescreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
        <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={UserDetail} />
        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
}
}

 export default App;
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: yes i write error on top before code

Comment: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Your redirection login is wrong... empty object evaluate to true, try setting user:null in constructor() instead of empty object

Comment: which version of react router is this?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"

Comment: same error when i set user null in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react router v4+ supports use of `PrivateRoute`.

```
// create a private route, if user is not logged in redirect to login page
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

Use it like a normal route and check authentication in the private route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/login" exact component={FormularAuth} />
  <PrivateRoute path='/private' component={Private} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

[Demo](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: i dont know how can we do it

Comment: yup by protected route method

Answer (score 0):

```js
//App.js 
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          user
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          user: null
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={(props)=><Landing {...props} users = {this.state.user}/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/homescreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in your landing Component check user value and navigate to respective routes.

```js
//Landing.js
class Landing extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.users) {
      this.props.history.push("homescreen")
    } else if (this.props.users === null) {
      this.props.history.push("login")
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>landing page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for response error resolve use privateRoute for redirect thank you again